# warning: Shift count >= width of type

Tags: ios, xcode

I do have such a code

```
data = new uint[2] { (uint)ul, (uint)(ul >> 32) };
```

on which xCode yells about `ul >> 32` piece of code with the subject's warning.
How to fix it?

Or better yet, how to disable these warnings, cause I have like 16 of them in a C++ code.

Comment: `ul >> 32` will always be 0, as a `uint` is a 32-bit unsigned integer. What are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to port some code from C# to C++ for an iOS project.
Here is the code
public BigInteger(ulong ul)
        {
            data = new uint[2] { (uint)ul, (uint)(ul >> 32) };
            length = 2;

            this.Normalize();
        }

Comment: Why is disabling the warning better than fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was pretty easy. The `ulong` type from C# is a 64 bit number, while in iOS is a 32 bit one. After changing the type in ios to `unsigned long long` everything worked and compiled as needed.

Comment: I always use `uint64_t` because it's clearer that I *need* it to be 64-bit.